# Finding square root without using math.sqrt()?

Tags: python, square-root

I recently was working on finding the square root of a number in `python` without using `sqrt()`. I came across this code and am having difficulty in understanding the logic in this code:

```
def sqrt(x):
    last_guess= x/2.0
    while True:
        guess= (last_guess + x/last_guess)/2
        if abs(guess - last_guess) < .000001: # example threshold
            return guess
        last_guess= guess
```

More specifically the logic behind calculating `guess` in above code. Can anyone help me understanding the logic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method

Comment: Please explain where you're stuck: your web search for "square root algorithm" should have turned up plenty of hits to answer your question.  This is also known as Newton's method (applied to square root) or the Babylonian method.

Comment: The logic: Initializes last guess to ½ the number. Computes a new guess which is the average of the last guess and the number divided by the last guess. Checks if this new value is is different enough from the last one to return it as the answer. If not, make the last guess the new and repeat the process. Assumes that each iteration of this averaging process will get closer to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the power (`**`) operator with an inverse exponent:

```
a = 2 ** (1.0 / 2)
a
> 1.41421...
```

Comment: ... although I suspect this is not quite what you were wanting to know...

Comment: simply `2 ** 0.5`

Comment: I know the power operator but wanted to understand the logic behind the code I mentioned in my post